# Photoshop - Multiple user woes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, read-only, multiple-users

Our office is currently having a problem with Photoshop with regards to multiple users working on the same file. For example 2 users can be editing the same file on the network creating confusion when one users drawing changes/reverts back to a state which is unrecognizable.

Is there a way to lock or notify the user that the file is in use (read-only).

Comment: I suspect telling staff to talk to each other isn't practical in this situation? If you make the file read-only, how will the user be able to save it?

Comment: What version of Photoshop?  I would contact Adobe and/or look for a plug-in that handles this for you.

Comment: I understand theirs a complete lack of communication i was just hoping there was a technical solution. I work extensively in autocad and if you open a file that's in use the program notifies you and asks you whether you'd like to open the file read only. I was just wondering, hoping adobe provided the same function. *Ramhound - We use elements 4, 5 & 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CC and you have your files on adobe's cloud there's a way to do it. If your files are stored in a local server then that all just depends on your server management software's features.

Photoshop itself doesn't have file handling features like that built in.